# NetworkManagerを使ったアクセスポイント化の設定について

Tags: linux, network, wifi

有線lanをPCにつないで，PCをアクセスポイント化してwifiを飛ばしてiphoneで利用したいのですが，接続がうまく行きません．使用しているOSはUbuntu18.04です．
Wifi設定から「wifiアクセスポイントをオンにする」を選択するとネットワーク名(SSID)とパスワードが自動的に設定されてiphoneからもwifiが見えるのですが，パスワードを入力して接続をしようとすると「インターネット未接続」という表示が出てネットにつなぐことができません．iphone -> PCのローカルな接続には成功しているようなのですが，そこから有線lanにつなぐことができていないみたいです．解決方法がわかる方は誰かいませんか？

Comment: やろうとしていることは恐らく**ブリッジ接続**かと思います。 - 参考: https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=17964

Answer (score 0):

普通はその手順で APモードにできます。
電波の状況が悪いということは考えられませんか？ 同じチャンネル使う機器が近くにあるとか。

以下のコマンドでチャンネル指定が可能です。

```
$ nm-connection-editor
```

2.4GHz帯は「1」「6」「11」。5.2GHz帯なら「36」「40」「44」「48」辺り。

参考:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/180733/how-to-setup-an-access-point-mode-wi-fi-hotspot

`wavemon` などで電波状況を調べることができます。

(ちなみにブリッジ接続ではありません)